# I can't figure out why my url rewrite isn't working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

Hey guys.
I'm new to url rewrites but I can't seem to figure out why this is not working

I have the link: http://thoughtsmash.com/profile.php?name=1

That I want to rewrite to: http://thoughtsmash.com/profilename/1

and I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/profilename/([0-9_]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

But it does nothing! The removal of the "www." works fine but the rest doesn't. Any ideas as to why? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^profilename/([0-9_]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

Note that I added `RewriteBase` and removed leading `/`

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately it's still not changing anything.

Comment: alright thanks for the help. Got any ideas as to why it's not working in my case?

Comment: @user607436: nope, it should work. I don't see any possibility to fail for such trivial rule.

Comment: Got it fixed! Something stupid on my part... :D thanks a bunch!